# How do I start solving this trigonometric system of equations?

Tags: trigonometry

**Question:**

> \begin{cases}
>     \tan x + \tan y = 1\\
>     x - y = \fracπ4
> \end{cases}

**My Try:**

> I've tried to apply sum to product formula but I can't do anything with it because it's $x-y$ in the other equality.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics! Please read [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). [PSQs](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33854/what-is-a-psq) (problem statement questions - where you just paste the problem and ask "what is the answer") do not belong on Math.SE. Consider adding context to the question such as what you've tried so far or what you're stuck on. Also, please use MathJax for formatting, not codeblocks. I assume `tgx` is meant to be $\tan(x)$? You can write that with `$\tan(x)$`.

Comment: I tried to visualize this with a little diagram and immediately found an almost trivial answer. I didn't even have to actually draw the diagram, it is that simple. Maybe think more about what the tangent looks like geometrically and don't rely so much on identity equations.

Comment: Well, rewriting $x-y=\frac{\pi}{4}$ gives $x=y+\frac{\pi}{4}$. That might be worth exploring after substitution into the first equation, but not sure. $$\text{}$$ Edit: I just tried it out, it DOES help.

Comment: Write $x=y+\tfrac{\pi}4$ and substitute that into the first equation, then solve for $\tan(y)$.

Answer (score 2):

I was passing by this forum for curiosity and stumbled upon your question, I was intrigued to solve and came with this, hope it can help.

Well, first things first, your system:

\begin{cases}
    \tan x + \tan y = 1\\
    x - y = \fracπ4
\end{cases}

First thing you want to do is isolate x (or y) in the second line, I'll do with x just because:

$$x = \fracπ4 + y$$

Then, plug your "new" value of x in the first equation:

$$\tan (\fracπ4 + y) + \tan y = 1$$

So, this doesn't help much right, but there is a trigonometry formula that states:

$$\tan(u±v)=\frac{\tan(u) ± \tan(v)}{1 ∓ \tan(u)\cdot\tan(v)}$$

Font: https://www.varsitytutors.com/hotmath/hotmath_help/topics/trigonometric-identities

It's pretty helpful, it will separate the elements inside of tangent and we will be able to work with them.

So,

$$\tan(\frac{\pi}{4} + y) + \tan (y) = 1\\$$

Turns in:

$$\frac{\tan(\frac{\pi}{4}) + \tan(y)}{1 - \tan(\fracπ4)\cdot\tan(y)} + \tan (y) = 1\\$$

From here is just simple algebra, hope that helps :)

Comment: See the [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/888233) for formatting.

Comment: Thank you @soupless I edited the answear with proper formatting.

Answer (score 1):

I finished the solution, that user **rookie** had offered.
$$
\frac{\tan(\frac{\pi}{4})+\tan(y)}{1-\tan(\frac{\pi}{4})\cdot\tan(y)}+\tan(y) =1,
\\
\left(\frac{1+\tan(y)}{1-\tan(y)}+\frac{\tan(y)-\tan^{2}(y)-1+\tan(y)}{1-\tan(y)}\right)=0,
\implies
\\
\implies
\begin{cases}
-\tan^{2}(y)+3\tan(y)=0,\\
{1-\tan(y)}\neq{0}.
\end{cases}
\iff
\begin{cases}
\tan(y)(\tan(y)-3)=0,\\
{\tan(y)}\neq{1}.
\end{cases}
\iff
\\
\iff
\bbox[lightgreen]
{
\begin{cases}
y=\pm{\pi{n}},\quad\arctan(3)\pm{\pi{n}},\quad{n}\in{Z},\\
{y}\neq{\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\pm\pi{n}\right),\quad{n}\in{Z}}.
\end{cases}
}
$$